# Is it possible to search in node_auto_index in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to search for any node inside node_auto_index inside neo4j?

I have indexes on both name and id columns and i want to issue a wild character search for both of them.

Currently i do this:

node_auto_index('name:xyz*') or node_auto_index('id:123*')

how do i combine both??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
node_auto_index('name:xyz* id:123*')
```

Answer (score 0):

The search string needs to comply with [Lucene Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/queryparsersyntax.html). In your example you could use

```
node_auto_index("'name:xyz*' or 'id:123'")
```

[not 100% sure if the quoting characters are correct]